# Store <key=val> in variable

Tags: pdfpages

I insert several PDFs thought my document using `\includepdf`. I'd like to define the `<key=val>` options in one variable and pass that to each `\includepdf`.

Right now I do something like this:

```
\includepdf[pages=-, frame, scale=0.8, offset=0mm -10mm, pagecommand={}]
                    {./parts/letter_1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-, frame, scale=0.8, offset=0mm -10mm, pagecommand={}]
                    {./parts/letter_2.pdf}
```

This is what I'd like to do, but this gives Package keyval Error...undefinded:

```
\newcommand{\PDFOptions}{pages=-, frame, scale=0.8, offset=0mm -10mm, pagecommand={}}
\includepdf[\PDFOptions]{./parts/letter_1.pdf}
\includepdf[\PDFOptions]{./parts/letter_2.pdf}
```

Comment: Can you try to replace `\newcommand` by `\def`? I believe that `\newcommand` comes with magic to allow optional arguments which does not work will with your use-cases.

In addition, you may need to write `\expandafter\includepdf\expandafter[\PDFOptions]` .

Comment: background/references for my comments requires in-depth understanding of TeX programming, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming/27589#27589

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger There's no difference whatsoever between doing that with `\newcommand` or `\def`. LaTeX won't expand the optional argument to `\includepdf` until it's too late for parsing the options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest strategy is to do

```
\newcommand{\myincludepdf}[2][]{%
  \includepdf[
    pages=-,
    frame,
    scale=0.8,
    offset=0mm -10mm,
    pagecommand={},
    #1
  ]{#2}%
}
```

and use

```
\myincludepdf{./parts/letter_1.pdf}
```

You may also *add* options, for instance

```
\myincludepdf[pages=1-3]{./parts/letter_1.pdf}
```

in a special case when you don't need all pages.